# Simple file read write code won't work

Tags: java

I have created a simple file read and write program. When compiling, the program shows no errors and runs without problem, but when I try to open the output file, I get a "file corrupted" error, and the size of the file is 0kb.

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Extention
{
     FileInputStream filein;
     FileOutputStream fileout;

     void asdf() throws IOException
     {
         InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
         System.out.print("/**");
         System.out.print("\n");
         System.out.print("* Created by Arul on 6/15/2016 *");
         System.out.print("\n");
         System.out.print("**/");
         System.out.print("\n");

         try {
            System.out.print("Enter Name of the file to read : ");
            filein = new FileInputStream(br.readLine());
            System.out.print("Enter Name of the file to write : ");
            fileout = new FileOutputStream(br.readLine());
            int i;
            do {
                i = filein.read();
                if (i == -1)
                    break;
                fileout.write(i);
            } while (i != -1);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
            System.out.println("Exception : File not found!");
        } finally {
            filein.close();
            fileout.close();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException
    {
        Extention d = new Extention();
        d.asdf();
    }
}
```

Comment: On my computer, it works fine

Comment: are you able to read and write all types of extentions?on my pc its not working for any extention including .java

Comment: I tried it with `.txt`. If you want to read binary files, then you need to read them using a byte-oriented stream, not a character oriented stream.

Comment: Works on mine, too - Mac with Java 8.

Comment: on my pc its only working from .java to .java only for other extentions getting file corrupted,can this be because of latest updated jdk

Comment: Your code is using byte-for-byte reading and writing. It should create identical copies of files. The format of the files, between JDKs should make no difference. Hackerdarshi suggested that you are using character orientated streams, but you are not - you are using FileInput and output streams so you're safe.

Comment: consider using System.out.println

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say, "File corrupted", is this a Java error which you get during execution of your program, or is this an error when you double click on the created file?

If it's the latter, it all depends on what you are trying to copy. If you used it to copy an TXT file, but you changed the file ending to MP3, you would find that, when you double click on the file, your media player will be selected to open the text file and won't understand the text data.

Comment: when i click on created file i get file corrupted.i tried to change the file to txt,and pdf

Comment: What program is trying to open the file (and complaining about it) and what is the extension of the file and what is the format? ie "Notepad++ is trying to open a file with extension .txt and the format of the file is MP3"

Comment: i converted the file to txt and tried to open it using notepad, then i tried to convert .java to pdf and tried to open it using foxit, in both cases i get file corrupted.

Comment: Nothing in your code deals with 'conversion'!! All your code does is copy from one file to the other. Note that changing a file extension (ie test.pdf to test.txt) does not change the format of the file. Basically, when you change your .java file (which is just text) to PDF, Foxit tries to open it but fails because it is trying to interpret the file as a PDF but it's not.

Comment: can you tell me how can i convert from one file format to another?

Comment: It's not a simple answer. If I have solved the mystery of why you are getting the error messages, please mark my answer as the solution and ask your conversion question as a whole new question on Stack Overflow. Conversion between file formats *can* be a messy, complicated process, depending on the formats involved and the availability of mature libraries to do it.